# Why can't renv find certain package versions?

Tags: r, renv

I am trying out `renv` for the first time on a project. I set up the `snapshot()` locally just fine and now I'm building a docker image for the project and running into issues with a couple packages.

The project has a lot of dependencies, and almost all of them are installing without issue, but the particular version of `data.table` threw an error:

```
#19 379.3 - Downloading data.table from CRAN ...            ERROR [downloaded length 0 != reported length 166]
#19 380.5 Warning: failed to find source for 'data.table 1.14.6' in package repositories
#19 380.5 Warning: error downloading 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/__linux__/jammy/latest/src/contrib/Archive/data.table/data.table_1.14.6.tar.gz' [downloaded length 0 != reported length 166]
#19 380.5 Error: failed to retrieve package 'data.table@1.14.6'
```

The entry in the `renv.lock` file was:

```
     "data.table": {
       "Package": "data.table",
       "Version": "1.14.6",
       "Source": "Repository",
       "Repository": "CRAN",
       "Requirements": [
         "R",
         "methods"
       ],
      "Hash": "aecef50008ea7b57c76f1cb5c127fb02"
     },
```

Well, the current version of `data.table` is 1.14.10, so I updated and in the next build that went fine, but it has me a little concerned about the reliability of `renv` for old package versions. It defeats the purpose of a reproducible environment if specified package versions aren't available and must be updated. When I visit [posit's package manager web client](https://packagemanager.posit.co/client/#/repos/cran/packages/overview?search=data.table) it lists `data.table` 1.14.6 in the archive, so why didn't it install?

Worth noting that I have not edited the `renv.lock` at all by hand. The current (working) entry is below. Are there particular items in this I should be checking? (Maybe the repository?)

```
"data.table": {
      "Package": "data.table",
      "Version": "1.14.10",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "RSPM",
      "Requirements": [
        "R",
        "methods"
      ],
      "Hash": "6ea17a32294d8ca00455825ab0cf71b9"
    },
```

Comment: The URL listed in the error seems to be correct, so it's a bit puzzling that the download failed.

Comment: I realized I made a commit with the old lockfile, so I was able to go back and see the data.table entry. Edited into the question now. The Repository did switch from CRAN (didn't work) to RSPM (did work). Perhaps that's a clue.

Comment: Yeah maybe, CRAN doesn't host older versions I think. But the error suggests it looked for CRAN and then created the correct RPSM URL anway..

Comment: @Axeman:  CRAN does host almost all older versions if it has ever released them.  The only intentional exceptions are where the package violated copyright or something and the uploader didn't have the right to submit it.  I suppose there are a few accidental exceptions too, but this isn't one of them.